# Using default File Symbols in C#

Tags: c#, windows

I want that a user can enter a filename and it shows him the "symbol" of the file.... like those ones:
[image]

I know that I could extract them out of their dlls and add them to my project, but I think there could be a solution which grabs them out of windows...
I would like to have a very simple implementation, because it'll be part of a school project and the examiners hate importing DLLs, it would be "unsafe", so , a function which is supported by C#'s default stuff would be very nice for me.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I thought there would be an easier way to do that.... 
I'll take a try embedding it. Thanks for your fast answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that is much much much easier than importing DLLs or such higher things.

```
  Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filename);
```

it returns an icon, so you have to convert it to an Image:

```
 (Image)new ImageConverter().ConvertFrom(Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filename));
```

It even extracts icons of .exe 's, which is even more than I asked for.
I'm really happy that I can provide an easier answer. Thanks Stackoverflow **☺**